# Jquery Select2 InitSelection Not Working

Tags: jquery

I am using [jQuery Select 2](https://select2.org/)

Its working fine but in edit mode when I am using **initSelection() method** for initialize a selected value I get this error :

```
Error: No select2/compat/initSelection
```

My jQuery script is:

```
jQuery('#country').select2({
            placeholder : 'Select Country',
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            ajax: {
                url: '<?php echo site_url('countries/get_countries')?>',
                dataType: 'json',
                type : 'GET',
                data: function(param) {
                    return {
                        countries : param.term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data) 
                {
                    var myResults = [];
                    $("#state").select2("val", "");
                    $("#city").select2("val", "");
                    jQuery.each(data, function(index,item) {
                        myResults.push({
                            id: item.id,
                            text: item.name
                        });
                    });
                    return {
                        results: myResults
                    };
                },
            },
            initSelection: function (element, callback) {
                var data = { id: 1, name: "Country Name" };
                callback(data);
            },
        });
```

In this example i just trying to load a test data.
Why do I have this error ?

Comment: The newer version doesn't have this function anylonger. I am searching for a replacement myself, but there's nothing I managed to find so far.

Comment: See [select2 - initselection error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30162458/1595213) for answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select2 - initselection error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919108/select2-initselection-error)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, you need to set the value of the fully init-ed element. Attach the select2 value setter to the end of your Select2 init code:

```
jQuery('#country').select2({ ... }).select2('val', []);
```

Or set some other value to trigger the initSelection method.

Answer (score 0):

For initSelection try this code

```
            initSelection: function (element, callback) {
                    var data = [];
                    $(element.val()).each(function () {
                        data.push({ id: this, text: this });
                    });
                    callback(data);
                }
```

For populating values use this.

```
      $('#').select2('data',arr);
```