# select2 - initselection error

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am getting the following error when using select2 plugin on `initSelection`.

`Error: Uncaught Error: No select2/compat/initSelection` is the error I am getting.

Hope somebody helps me in sorting out the `inistselection` issue.

JS:

```
  $(".doctor_id_pat").select2({
    placeholder: "Search Users",
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
        url: "/listallergiesajax",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function(term) {
            return {
                q: term
            };
        },
        results: function(data, page) {
            return {

                results: $.map(data, function(item) {

                    return {
                        text: item.text,
                        id: item.id
                    }
                })

            };
        },
    },
    initSelection: function(element, callback) {

        $.ajax("/listallergiesajax", {
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(data) {

            callback(data.results[0]);

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `$(".doctor_id_pat").select2({});` what is select2?

Comment: It is a plugin for select options. @ashkufaraz

Comment: Deprecated in Select2 4.0. This has been replaced by another option and is only available in the full builds of Select2.

Answer (score 25):

Select2 v3.5.2 uses the `initSelection` method. Select2 v4 has a different approach.

For information on how to upgrade (`initSelection` and other stuff) see https://select2.org/upgrading/migrating-from-35#removed-the-requirement-of-initselection.

Comment: This information has changed to [this link](https://select2.org/upgrading/migrating-from-35#removed-the-requirement-of-initselection).

Comment: @joost, I had exact same problem as cr0ss but this does not help me by just referencing to select2 resource as it is poorly documented. It is better to correct cr0ss code in his question to make it working. So other people like me can see how the working code look like. Hope you see this point. Thanks!